# PHP Using a Session cookie ID set by 3rd party server/URL

Tags: php, wordpress, session-cookies

I am building a WordPress shopping cart plugin that will tie into our server through a URL that will produce an XML page, which I will then have to parse the info to the WordPress page.

The server contains a `session id (ShoppingCart.SessionID)` that I need to get and use to help store which button was clicked and then pull the product info and add it to the cart. Each `button` is given a `product id` via `shortcode (product_id="some#")` from the page owner and that ID is pulled from the server to display the product's info.

**How the buttons are set up:**

In the shortcode file, I am using a function and have the button set up as

```
<?php
add_shortcode('add_cart_button', 'add_cart_button_handler');

function add_cart_button_handler($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'product_id' => '',
    ), $atts));
    return print_add_cart_button_for_product($product_id, $atts);
}
```

**In the main plugin file:**

This file handles the printing of the button and the function to display the cart

```
<?php
session_id();
session_start();

// This function prints the button with its assigned $product_id

function print_add_cart_button_for_product($product_id, $atts = array()) {
    $replacement .= '<form method="POST" class="cart-button-form" style="display:inline" action="">';
    $replacement .= '<input type="hidden" name="bmt_cart_product" value="' . $product_id . '" />';

    $replacement .= '</form>';
    $replacement .= '</div>';
    return $replacement;
}
```

**Here is the function for what is supposed to be displaying the cart/product info:**

```
function show_shopping_cart_handler($atts) {
    $output = "";
    $form = '';
    $output .= '<table style="width: 100%;">';

    $output .= '<tr class="cart_item_row">
        <th class="cart_item_name_th">' . (__("Item Name", "wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart")) . '</th><th class="cart_price_th">' . (__("Price", "wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart")) . '</th><th></th>
        </tr>';

# For now, I am using this to print the headers that display the
# ShoppingCart.SessionID="somevalue", but on every button click it changes the value of the session id.

    if (isset($_POST['add_cart_submit'])) {

// The server reads the ID from "&PRODUCTID=product#"
            $id = "&PRODUCTID=" . $_POST['cart_product'];
            $url = "https://secure.bmtmicro.com/cart?CID=2/WP" . $id;
            $options = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'content' => http_build_query($data)
                )
            );
            //$context = stream_context_create($options);
            $context = stream_context_set_default($options);
            $output .= file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        }
        print_r(get_headers($url));

       $output .= '</table>';
       return $output;
}
```

**What the XML page looks like with an example product**

Not sure if this is needed, but the more info provided, the better (right?). The product ID that is sent will populate these fields and keep adding a new row and then I will parse the necessary fields to the WordPress page.

```
<shoppingcart sessionid="88582813">
  <producttable>
   <row number="0">
    <productid>22804</productid>
    <productname>XFree86 CD</productname>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <productprice>$15.00</productprice>
    <discount>$0.00</discount>
    <rowtotal>$15.00</rowtotal>
   </row>
  </producttable>
 </shoppingcart>
```

I am pretty new to PHP and learning as I go (reading/research), but have not been able to find the solution or steps to tackle my issue. Essentially, I believe my question should be (in short):

How can I grab the `ShoppingCart.SessionID` from the 3rd party server and use it to populate the cart without refreshing the Session so more than one product will display when more than one button is clicked? Also, is there a better/more productive way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance and let me know if there's any info I need to add to the question!

Comment: Why exactly are you using a 3rd party session id. Wouldn't it be much simpler to just use your own session id? I assume you can't modify the session data (since it's 3rd party).

Comment: Apparently the server stores it's own session cookie. My original plan was to get an API key and just make requests, but this is apparently the route I'm being told to go...

Comment: I'm still not really sure what problem you have. Do you need the session id to query the store API or to manage the users basket?

Comment: I believe the users basket. Once they have their item(s) in there, they will click to checkout which will then take them to our separate checkout, so (if I can think of this properly), the selected items should still be stored in the session from our server and pass right to the checkout page

Comment: When you do the handoff you need to pass the session id.

Comment: Don't I have to get the ID? I can get it to print by using the `print_r(get_headers());`, but it just keeps creating a new session every time a button is clicked. How would I get the session id to store it?

Comment: The session is stored on the 3rd party server and the session id cookie is stored in the user's cookiejar. You can't get the id from the user because you can't access 3rd party cookiejars, so the server has to give it to you; either by giving it to you at the moment of handoff or giving you some other means of requesting the session id.

Comment: How can I go about getting it? Most everything I've seen has been getting the session from another one of their php files, not really a 3rd party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In case anyone comes across this with a similar issue:**

My way around this was to send the `button` data to an `<iframe>` and then set the `<iframe>` to `width="0" height="0"`.

Example code:

```
<form method="POST" action="URL" target="the_iframe">
  // add some <input> fields data
</form>

<iframe type="hidden" name="the_iframe" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

Not sure if this is THE BEST way to do it, but it works and I was able to add some JQuery to manipulate things even further (I tried using AJAX before this, but the server was set to "same origin", so the data wouldn't send from another URL).